# Python http.server on port 8000 works while xmlrpc.server on port 8000 refuses connection

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am trying to figure out why

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

works, while

```
python rpc_server.py 8000
```

refuses a connection from remote hosts. My rpc_server.py code is taken verbatim from: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.server.html

When I make a GET request to the http.server, everything works fine, both locally and remotely (router is correctly forwarding requests). Similarly, when I ping the rpc_server from the same machine (localhost), I get a response. However, when I ping the rpc_server from another machine (remote host), I get 'connection refused'. Using tcpdump, I can see that when I submit a SYN request the response is always RST. Why is the SimpleXMLRPCServer sending a reset signal to all remote host requests but not local host requests? (I have tried sending the remote host request using both POSTMAN in Chrome and rpc_client.py [taken from the same tutorial above]).

Comment: Taken verbatim from which part of it? Anyways, if you’re using `("localhost", 8000)`, it should be `("0.0.0.0", 8000)` to match `http.server` defaults.

Comment: Holy crap that worked!